# C++ class inheritance with "get" method

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, static-methods, static-members

I want to create a base class containing mostly static members/methods, like:

```cpp
class LuaObject {
    public:
        static const luaL_Reg Methods[];

        static int Create(lua_State *L);

        static LuaObject* get(lua_State *L, int pos) {
            return *(LuaObject**)luaL_checkudata(L, pos, LuaObject::Metatable);
        }
};
```

and then derive from that for specific types of objects:

```cpp
class Pulse: public LuaObject {
    public:
        int n;
    //...
};

const luaL_Reg Pulse::Methods[] = {
    //...
};

static int Pulse::Create(lua_State *L) {
    Pulse **ud = (Pulse**)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(Pulse*));
    *ud = new Pulse();
    //...
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to go about this without a lot of copy and paste (defeating the purpose of `LuaObject`). Two problems arise:

1. I get errors such as: `error: ISO C++ does not permit ‘LuaObject::Methods’ to be defined as ‘Pulse::Methods’ [-fpermissive]` and `error: no ‘int Pulse::Create(lua_State*)’ member function declared in class ‘Pulse’`. i.e. it seems like `Pulse` doesn't inherit the static members/methods from `LuaObject`.
2. The `get(L, n)` method is intended to return a pointer to the class instance, e.g. I want to be able to write:

   ```
   Pulse *p = Pulse::get(L,1);
   printf("p->n = %d\n", p->n);
   ```

   However, it seems like since `get` is only defined for `LuaObject`, I'd get a `LuaObject*`, not a `Pulse*`.

How can I address these issues without having to copy `Methods`, `Create`, `get` etc into `Pulse` (and all other classes derived from `LuaObject`)?
I thought turning it into a template might help:

```cpp
template <class T>
class LuaObject {
    public:
        static const luaL_Reg Methods[];

        static int Create(lua_State *L);

        static T* get(lua_State *L, int pos) {
            return *(T**)luaL_checkudata(L, pos, T::Metatable);
        }
};

class Pulse: public LuaObject<Pulse> {
    public:
        //...
};
```

But even this gave the same errors, so I'm stumped.

**edit:** As requested, a minimal example program, including the compile errors: (build with `g++ test.cpp -Llua -Lpulse -o test`)

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <pulse/pulseaudio.h>

class LuaObject {
    public:
        static const char *Metatable;
        static const luaL_Reg Methods[];

        static void InitModule(lua_State *L);
        static int Create(lua_State *L);

        //Retrieve object instance from Lua stack at specified position
        static LuaObject* get(lua_State *L, int pos) {
            return *(LuaObject**)luaL_checkudata(L, pos, LuaObject::Metatable);
        }
};


class Pulse: public LuaObject {
    //Here I want to avoid having to declare/define Metatable, get() etc again.
    public:
        static int getEvent(lua_State *L);
        pa_context *ctx;
};



const char *Pulse::Metatable = "pulse"; //error: ISO C++ does not permit ‘LuaObject::Metatable’ to be defined as ‘Pulse::Metatable’ [-fpermissive]
const luaL_Reg Pulse::Methods[] = { //error: ISO C++ does not permit ‘LuaObject::Methods’ to be defined as ‘Pulse::Methods’ [-fpermissive]
    {"getEvent", Pulse::getEvent},
    {NULL, NULL}
};


//Set up the "pulse" module in a Lua state
static void Pulse::InitModule(lua_State *L) { //error: no ‘void Pulse::InitModule(lua_State*)’ member function declared in class ‘Pulse’
    if(luaL_newmetatable(L, Pulse::Metatable)) {
        luaL_setfuncs(L, Pulse::Methods, 0);
    }
    lua_pop(L, 1); //remove metatable from Lua stack, leave in Lua registry

    static luaL_Reg lib[] = {
        {"new", Pulse::Create},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };
    luaL_newlibtable(L, lib);
    lua_setglobal(L, "pulse");
}

//Called from Lua (as pulse.new()) to create a Pulse object
static int Pulse::Create(lua_State *L) { //error: no ‘int Pulse::Create(lua_State*)’ member function declared in class ‘Pulse’
    Pulse **ud = (Pulse**)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(Pulse*));
    *ud = new Pulse();
    return 1;
}


//Called from Lua (as myPulse:getEvent()) to read events
int Pulse::getEvent(lua_State *L) {
    //We only have L as parameter; the Pulse object is on the Lua stack,
    //so we need to read it using luaL_checkudata() (which is handled
    //by get())
    Pulse *self = Pulse::get(L, 1); //error: invalid conversion from ‘LuaObject*’ to ‘Pulse*’ [-fpermissive]

    //pretend get_pulse_event() is defined in pulseaudio.h (the actual mechanism
    //is much more complex and wouldn't help the example)
    int event = get_pulse_event(self->ctx);
    lua_pushinteger(L, event);
    return 1;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    Pulse::InitModule(L);
    return luaL_dofile(L, "main.lua");
}
```

Comment: Hmm... why do you need an object with all static methods in the first place? Maybe those static methods should just be standalone methods. Kind of like it is done in standard library with containers and algorithms. Also it looks very strange that a `get` method is static. It looks more like a design problem. That being said, the question, why your attempt doesn't work, is interesting anyways.

Comment: The idea is for the inherited classes such as `Pulse` to all have those same methods, without having to duplicate them. I'm not sure how else to go about it. `get` is needed because Lua only gives a `void*`. (I guess I could cast, but that's a bit ugly)

Comment: No, no, no. I wasn't asking about inheritance. I was asking why is everything static. It is confusing. Something like `get` should be tied to an instance, at least that is my gut feeling. You should also post a minimal offending example. It seems like you redeclared a static member in derived class and messed up some more things.

Comment: `get` can't be tied to an instance, because it's how we retrieve the instance in the first place. When Lua calls our methods it only passes a `lua_State*`, and we have to retrieve the actual parameters (such as the `Pulse*`) from that.

Answer (score 1):

static members from base have to be defined for base. If you want to define them for the derived class you have to declare them again. That doesn't mean you don't have access to static members from derived, although you have to be aware that static members cannot be declared `virtual`

btw: `static` can only be specified inside the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

What your are trying to do will not work in the way you think.

```
class ClassWithoutStaticMembers {
private:
    int myInt; 
public:
   void someFunc();
};

void ClassWithoutStaticMembers::someFunc() {
    // Here we can access member variable myInt in two ways:
    myInt = 10; // directly

    this->myInt = 12; // Using the pointer (this) that belongs to the class.
}

// When you declare functions that have static storage space
// They do not have the class's (this) pointer associated with them

class ClassWithStaticMembers {
public:
    static int x;
    void someFunc();
    static void someStaticFunc();
};

void ClassWithStaticMembers::someFunc() {
    x = 3; // valid
    this->x = 9; // valid because x does belong to this class but is of static storage type
}

void ClassWithStaticMembers::someStaticFunc() {
    this->(anything); // not valid this pointer is not associated with this static member function.
} 

// You can still inherit from the second class, but the static member
// function is not defined in your derived classes. However you
// can still access that function either through an object
// or without referencing that object.

class DerivedA : public ClassWithStaticMembers {
public:
    void anotherFunc();
};

int main() {
    DerivedA a;
    a.someStaticFunc(); // this is valid;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    // Here we do not declare a variable of type ClassWithStaticMembers 
    // or DerivedA but we can access ::someStaticFunc() from either since 
    // it is declared public in the base class

    ClassWithStaticMembers::someStaticFunc(); // We invoke this function call - valid.
    DerivedA::someStaticFunc(); // We Invoke this function again because
    // DerivedA inherits publicly from ClassWithStaticMembers.
    return 0;
}

// Now if we go back to the class definition of DerivedA and look at its member function anotherFunc();
void DerivedA::anotherFunc() {
    // Here we can use DerivedA this pointer to access the static function
    // because it is a member of this class's base type
    this->someStaticFunc(); // This is valid and will invoke the static function call
}
```